# Make a search string in Firebase and do some stuff in case exist or do other in case doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my problem is when I search for a user in mi firebase database

```
 public void readUsers(){   final String userame =
 etUserName.getText().toString();
          Query query = mUsersDatabaseReference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userame);
         query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     String userName = (String) userSnapshot.child("userName").getValue();

                     Toast.makeText(RegistryActivity.this, userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                     String userNameUpper = userName.toLowerCase();
                     String etUserUpper = userame.toLowerCase();
                     if (etUserUpper.equals(userNameUpper)){
                        // Toast.makeText(RegistryActivity.this, userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         alertConfirmUserName();


                     }else(){
                         registerUser();
                         Toast.makeText(RegistryActivity.this, "No exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     }
                 }
             }

             @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         }); }
```

as you can see i read the database and i know the user exist, but i want to do a register in case the user dont exist, but this always enter only in the if and if the user dont exist, dont do the else...... I try changing for 
 mUsersDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() 
without the query, but it always enter in the code above

```
  if (userNameUpper.equals(etUserUpper)){
                         alertConfirmUserName();
                         break;

                     }else {
                         Toast.makeText(RegistryActivity.this, "Dont exist ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Without the query always do the if and go to the else, it doestn matter if i have a break or return always go to the else.
I only want to verify the username dont exist and if dont exist,register a new User.

Answer (score 0):

I recomand you using an unique identifier such as `uid` or `email address` like this:

```
firebase-root
   |
   ---- users
          |
          ---- uid1
          |      |
          |      ---- name: John
          |
          ---- uid2
          |      |
          |      ---- name: Dave
          //and so on
```

or

```
firebase-root
   |
   ---- users
          |
          ---- name1@email,com
          |      |
          |      ---- name: John
          |
          ---- name2@email,com
          |      |
          |      ---- name: Dave
          //and so on
```

Than to check if a user exists in the you database, put a listener on `users node` and call `exists()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userEmail);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // Create user
        } else {
            // Do what you want
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i already have this, i dont put the code here, but the next step is try to create a new user and first verify if the user email exist. In my database i have uniqueID and email per user, but because i have a search for user, i need unique userNames in every new user register.

Comment: If you'll not find any other solution, give it a try. Will work for sure ;)